# Python IndexError: list index out of range when using iterations

Tags: python

I've been trying to download screenshots from the App Store and here's my code (I'm a beginner).

The problem I encounter is `list index out of range at line 60 (screenshotList = data["results"][resultCounter]["screenshotUrls"]`

The thing is that sometimes, the search API returns 0 results for the search term used, and therefore it gets messed up because `"resultCount" = 0`.

I'm not sure what else it could be/nor how I can fix it. Any help?

```
# Required libraries
import urllib
import string
import random
import json
import time

""" screenshotCounter is used so that all screenshots have a different name
resultCounter is used to go from result to result in downloaded JSON file
"""

screenshotCounter = 0
resultCounter = 0

""" Create three random letters as search term on App Store
Download JSON results file
Shows used search term
"""

searchTerm = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(3)))
urllib.urlretrieve("https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=us&entity=software&limit=3&term=" + str(searchTerm), "download.txt")
print "Used search term: " + str(searchTerm)

# Function to download screenshots + give it a name + confirmation msg
def download_screenshot(screenshotLink, screenshotName):
urllib.urlretrieve(screenshotLink, screenshotName)
print "Downloaded with success:" + str(screenshotName)

# Opens newly downloaded JSON file
with open ('download.txt') as data_file:
data = json.load(data_file)

""" Get the first list of screenshots from stored JSON file,
resultCounter = 0 on first iteration
"""
screenshotList = data["results"][resultCounter]["screenshotUrls"]

# Gives the number of found results and serves as iteration limit
iterationLimit = data["resultCount"]

# Prints the number of found results
print str(iterationLimit) + " results found."

""" Change the number of iterations to the number of results, which will be 
different for every request, minus 1 since indexing starts at 0
"""

iterations = [0] * iterationLimit

""" For each iteration (number of results), find each screenshot in the
screenshotList, name it, download it. Then change result to find the next
screenshotList and change screenshotList variable.
"""
for number in iterations:
for screenshotLink in screenshotList:
    screenshotName = "screenshot" + str(screenshotCounter) + ".jpeg"
    download_screenshot(screenshotLink, screenshotName)
    screenshotCounter = screenshotCounter + 1
resultCounter = resultCounter + 1
screenshotList = data["results"][resultCounter]["screenshotUrls"]
# Sleeping to avoid crash
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: One possibility is to check the length of `data["results"]` and not do anything if it's 0. Another might be to loop over the items in `data["results"]` instead of indexing.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. Instead of "not doing anything" I'd rather search again for a term that doesn't return 0 results. Should I use a function?

Comment: Your code fails as you try to index an empty list, if you look at download.txt it will be pretty obvious what is happening.`data["results"] -> []` `[][0]-> indexError`

Comment: You could put the whole thing in a function, or you could use a loop that keeps checking and breaks once you get results.

Comment: Also fix your indentation, it is impossible to tell what is in or outside your function

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code to check for the presence of results before trying anything. If there aren't any, it goes back through the loop with a new search term. If there are, it will stop at the end of that iteration.

```
# Required libraries
import urllib
import string
import random
import json
import time

    # Function to download screenshots + give it a name + confirmation msg
def download_screenshot(screenshotLink, screenshotName):
    urllib.urlretrieve(screenshotLink, screenshotName)
    print "Downloaded with success:" + str(screenshotName)

success = False
while success == False: 

    """ Create three random letters as search term on App Store
    Download JSON results file
    Shows used search term
    """

    searchTerm = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(3)))
    urllib.urlretrieve("https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=us&entity=software&limit=3&term=" + str(searchTerm), "download.txt")
    print "Used search term: " + str(searchTerm)



    # Opens newly downloaded JSON file
    with open ('download.txt') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    """ Get the first list of screenshots from stored JSON file,
    resultCounter = 0 on first iteration
    """
    resultCount = len(data["results"])
    if  resultCount == 0:
        continue #if no results, skip to the next loop

    success = True
    print str(resultCount) + " results found."

    for j, resultList in enumerate(data["results"]):
        screenshotList = resultList["screenshotUrls"]

        """ For each iteration (number of results), find each screenshot in the
        screenshotList, name it, download it. Then change result to find the next
        screenshotList and change screenshotList variable.
        """
        for i, screenshotLink in enumerate(screenshotList):
            screenshotName = "screenshot" + str(i) + '_' + str(j) + ".jpeg"
            download_screenshot(screenshotLink, screenshotName)
    # Sleeping to avoid crash
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot. does the "success = True" is equal to "else: success = True" ?

Comment: thanks! ok, the only thing I'd like to do now is go back to the beginning (search with a new random string) once I have my screenshots--so that I have a huge database of screenshots from different apps. Right now the code stops when I have a few screenshots. I don't think I can do that using while--do I go the function way?

Comment: To answer your first question: Sort of. Under other circumstances it might not be, but in this case, if the if-statement is true, then the rest of the code in the loop is skipped because I used `continue`. So the line `success = True` will never run unless the if-statement is false.

Comment: You could keep track of how many screenshots you've gotten -- increment some counter by len(screenshotList) inside the `for j, resultList in enumerate(data["results"]):` then end the `while` loop when the counter is over some limit.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

```
try:
    for screenshotLink in screenshotList:
        screenshotName = "screenshot" + str(screenshotCounter) + ".jpeg"
        download_screenshot(screenshotLink, screenshotName)
        screenshotCounter = screenshotCounter + 1
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: Nothing  in the code you have provided is indexing anything, what are you going to catch?